# Usage of Existential Quantifiers in Description Logic

Tags: ontology, description-logic

I have difficulty understanding this statement in DL:

∃R.∃S.C(a)

What does this proposition exactly mean? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that the individual named *a* belongs to the concept ∃*R*.∃*S*.*C*. The concept ∃*R*.∃*S*.*C* represents the class of things that have a relation *R* with something that has a relation *S* with something that is in the class denoted by *C*. For instance, if *R* is the relation `married to`, *S* is the relation `works for` and *C* is the class of `Public organisations`, then ∃*R*.∃*S*.*C* represents all the entities that are married to something (or someone) that works for a public organisation. Then ∃*R*.∃*S*.*C*(*a*) means that the individual named *a* is such an entity.